# reCAPTCHA の商用サイトでの利用にあたってライセンス制限はありますか？

Tags: ライセンス, recaptcha

GoogleのreCAPTCHA V2を導入しようと考えていますが、ライセンスに関して不安があるので質問させていただきます。

reCAPTCHAを商用サイトで使用しようと思うのですが、商用使用などの制限はありますか？V1はソースコードが[GitHub](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/)にBSDライセンスで公開されているようなのですが、V2の方がわかりません。

インターネット上で調べて見ましたが、明確に書かれているものがなかったため質問させていただいた次第です。どなたか分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 参考: [Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/)

Answer (score 4):

コメントにリンクが貼られていますが、Google APIs Terms of Serviceに準拠する限り無料で利用できます。

またPHPのクライアントライブラリ自体のバージョンはv1.1.2となっていますが、エンドポイントはv2のものになっているので、reCAPTCHA V2対応しています。
https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/SocketPost.php#L48